# Is it possible to fade out a video using "CCVideoPlayer"

Tags: video, cocos2d-iphone, ccvideoplayer

I am playing a video in cocos2d using "CCVideoPlayer" and I am wondering if there is a way to fade the video out towards the end? what I mean by fading out the video is, usually the video just stops abruptly at the end and i am needing to be able to slowly fade it out instead of the video just coming to an abrupt end.

Comment: Fade out the video itself (to black) or fade out the whole CCVideoPlayer component (to transparent)?

Comment: The whole CCVideoPlayer component!

Comment: could you fade in a black layer over the video?

Comment: I already have a back ground image that gets shown right after the video stops playing and I need to be able to slowly fade the video out to this image.

Comment: maybe fade the image in on top? then remove player and top image to show the image below once it is fully visible